# create permutation variable importance after using train instead of fit

Tags: python

I tried to use this permutation code:

```
perm_importance = permutation_importance(model, x_test, y_test, random_state=7)
```

Error seen:

```
"TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method"
```

**The question:**
Is there a way to create permutation variable importance after using xgb.train instead of xgb.fit?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide more information regarding what you are trying to do, and what you are using? (libraries, etc)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.